# what is the way to add max_solutions and max_seconds parameters to Python MIP Optimization model?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am using python's MIP module for optimization. I have set up a model with few parameters. I would want to limit the number of solutions and add stop timer if I don't find any solution in given time. I have added these parameters as given below:

```
m = Model(name='opt', sense=MAXIMIZE, solver_name=CBC)
m.optimize(max_solutions=1, max_seconds= 300)
```

somehow none of them seem working to me. it does not even stop looking for a solution after given time and it returns 2 solution sometimes even if I want to limit it to 1. Is there something I am missing in syntax?

One more thing, Gurobi has an option to add multiple variable using add_Vars parameter. Is there anything similar available in MIP too?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, which version of Python-MIP are you using?

Comment: Wanted to edit and add a `python-mip` tag but it doesn't exist. While several questions regarding Python-MIP have been posted, a search for its name (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python-MIP) yields related questions but also many unrelated ones about eg. Gurobi, Pyomo, PuLP and OR-Tools. Similar to Pyomo and PuLP, there could be a new `python-mip` tag to help find question related to this library. As the project became part of COIN-OR in 2019, I'd expect the volume of questions to keep growing. I leave this open for discussion.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.6 and  mip=1.9.3

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I have been doing some tests myself (with the Python-MIP solver) and seen some similar issues. Apparently it's still quite new and many improvements have been implemented recently or are yet to be developed. I will post from what I've learned:

1. regarding `max_seconds`: There's been at least one (closed) issue [on the official repo](https://github.com/coin-or/python-mip/issues/48) related to using `max_seconds` parameter and CBC.
2. regarding `max_solutions`: If you are using version 1.6.2 or before, [here's an explanation](https://github.com/coin-or/python-mip/issues/32) for that: until 1.6.1, the `m.optimize(max_solutions=1)` wasn't setting the maximum solution parameter to CBC. In that case you should try with the following lines (or just update to current version):

   `m.max_solutions = 1`

   `m.optimize()`

If the former don't help for the `max_seconds` and `max_solutions` parameters, I guess you'd better post your question as an issue at the library's repo to get answers and support from the project contributors.

3. Adding multiple variables, similar to gurobipy's `Model.addVars()` method: Yes, you can do it as follows

   ```
    p = {(i, j): m.add_var(var_type=CONTINUOUS, lb=0, name="p[%d,%d]" % (i, j))
    for i in Set_i for j in Set_j}
   ```

In this example, we are adding a variable `p_ij` and specifying it's continuous
(vs. binary or integer), has lower bound 0, and the sets where the indexes run. `Set_i` and `Set_j` are Python lists. See the documentation [here](https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes.html#mip.Model.add_var) for a more detailed explanation on how to use it. Similarly, you can create indexed constraints using the [add_constr method](https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes.html#mip.Model.add_constr), similar to Gurobi's `Model.AddConstrs()` method.

Comment: I tried m.max_solutions = 1 before, but it is somehow not working too. when i check the command prompt while running the optimization, it does say that "Result - Stopped on solution limit", but m.num_solutions returns 2 when i had set max solutions to 1 only.